# GWT integration with SmartGWT - Cant select text SectionStack->Section->Canvas->HTML

Tags: gwt, integration, smartgwt

we've used a combination of GWT and smart gwt to add some features to an app we've built.

The problem I have is that we decided to make use of the accordion functionality (SectionStack's) that SmartGWT offers and we are nesting our stock gwt widget inside a canvas and then nesting that inside the section stack. E.G

SectionStack(SmartGWT)->Section(SmartGWT)->Canvas (SmartGWT)->VerticalPanel(GWT) -> Other GWT Widgets (HTML, labels etc)

Before we mixed GWT and SmartGWT it was possible to select text in the standard GWT widgets and then copy and paste etc. Nesting the GWT widgets in the SmartGWT canvas means this is now not possible. Can anyone offer an explanation why this is the case and/or a solution on how to fix it.

I've tried `canvas.setCanSelectText(true);`  but this doesn't seem to do anything either.

We're using GWT 2.1 with SmartGWT 2.2. The demo app using SmartGWT2.2 seems to exhibit the same problem over at http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_gwt_integration . I've also tried GWT 2.0.x with SmartGWT 2.2

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For those interested I've managed to find a bug registered for this at : http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=391&q=GWT%20integration&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Reporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I've managed to find a bug registered for this at : code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/…

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not an issue. You have to call the *setCanSelectText* method on the *WidgetCanvas* wich is wrapping your GWT widget. The *WidgetCanvas* is created in the *addItem(Widget)* method. One way to go is to override the *addItem* method like this:

```
@Override
public void addItem(Widget widget) {
    if (widget instanceof Canvas) {
        addItem((Canvas) widget);
    } else {
        WidgetCanvas wg = new WidgetCanvas(widget);
        wg.setCanSelectText(true);
        addItem(wg);
    }
}
```